# Scraping multiple values from a table with the same selectors in a loop using node js and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I wrote this code to retrieve some data:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const BETEXPLORER_URL = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/spain/laliga/eibar-valencia/lOk6RMqo/`;

(async () => {
  /* Initiate the Puppeteer browser */
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  /* Go to the page and wait for it to be loaded */
  await page.goto(BETEXPLORER_URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  /* Run javascript inside of the page */
  let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let book = document.querySelector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.h-text-left.over-s-only > a').innerText;
    let odd1 = document.querySelector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.table-main__detail-odds.table-main__detail-odds--first.js-has-aodds > span').innerText;
    let oddX = document.querySelector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6) > span').innerText;
    let odd2 = document.querySelector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(7) > span').innerText;
    /* Returning an object filled with the scraped data */
    return {
        book,
        odd1,
        oddX,
        odd2
    }
  });
  /* Outputting what we scraped */
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I'd like to get all values with the same selector from a table's rows. I think I should do it with a loop, but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the rows with their number: `tr:nth-child(n)`.

### Steps

1.) Define an object structure, in my example I used a JavaScript class `Item`, you can use anything else of course that you prefer. Then create an empty array (`data`) where we can collect all instances of the table rows.

2.) Get the exact number of table rows (`tableLength` in the example, you will need to add + 1 to its value in the loop to reach the last item as well).

3.) Write a for loop that iterates over all `<tr>`-s.

4.) The data from the `<td>`-s can be retrieved with their exact selectors where: `tr:nth-child(${ **number of row** })`

5.) With each iteration create a new `Item` with the actual scraped strings and push it to the main object (the empty array we've defined at the beginning).

### Example code:

```js
const data = []

class Item {
  constructor(book, odd1, oddX, odd2) {
    this.book = book
    this.odd1 = odd1
    this.oddX = oddX
    this.odd2 = odd2
  }
}

const tableLength = await page.$$eval('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr', el => el.length)

// iterate over tr:nth-child(${i}) on all rows
  for (let i = 1; i < tableLength + 1; i++) {
    const book = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td.h-text-left.over-s-only > a`))
    const odd1 = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td.table-main__detail-odds.table-main__detail-odds--first.js-has-aodds > span`))
    const oddX = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(6) > span`))
    const odd2 = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(7) > span`))

    const actualItem = new Item(book, odd1, oddX, odd2)
    data.push(actualyItem)
  }
  console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just iterate over the trs:

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  let trs = document.querySelectorAll('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr')
  return [...trs].map(tr => {
    return {
      book: tr.querySelector('td.h-text-left.over-s-only > a').innerText,
      ...
    }
  })
}
```